# Python open file with subprocess.call, which filename and path is stored in sqlite database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, file, subprocess

I'm making a QR code scanner with Python. I have a database where the primary key ID is stored in the QR code. If I scan the QR code, I want to open the file whose path+filename is stored in database column called **Audiofile**. If the QR code contains the path+filename, the audio file is to start playing. I made a GUI for it where I can upload several types of audio files and all the uploaded filenames and paths are stored in **Audiofile** in the database.

Here is my record in the database:

[image: DATABASE URL LINK FOR IMAGE]

So my QR code contains the **testid**, which is *73a380e8-b5d1-11ec-8de8-b827eb5d6f55* and if I read this QR code, I want to open the **audiofile**, which is */home/pi/Desktop/audiotodb/rocky1.mp3*.
How is it possible that from the ID I can open the **audiofile** with `subprocess.call(['open', a])`?

Here is the Python code, which is working with the QR code, which contains the URL:

```py
import cv2
import time
import os, subprocess

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
prevData = " "

while True:
    check, img = cap.read()
    data, bbox, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(img)

    if data:
        a=data
        if data == prevData:
            continue

        if data == a:
            subprocess.call(['open', a])
            print(a)
        prevData = data
    cv2.imshow("QR Code detector", img)

    if(cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q")):
        break
```

Comment: What platform are you running on? By the way, you should really only use "code snippets" for including executable **JavaScript** code that we can execute by clicking on the **Run code snippet** button.

Comment: Also, you have `a=data` and then you check `if data == a:` How can this last check ever be `False`? And is `a` is at this point the full path to the audio file or something else? We need to know what this is.